# Reconstructing SVD in Python

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I'm looking at performing SVD in Python with Numpy. Taking the example from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) page

```
from numpy.linalg import svd
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1,0,0,0,2],[0,0,3,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,4,0,0,0]])
u, s, v = svd(M)
```

If I try to reconstruct `M` from `u`, `s`, and `v` the first thing I need to do is create sigma, the covariance matrix, from `s`.

```
sigma = np.diag(s)
print(sigma)
[[ 4.          0.          0.          0.       ]
 [ 0.          3.          0.          0.       ]
 [ 0.          0.          2.23606798  0.       ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.       ]]
```

However this produces a 4x4 matrix though, not the 4x5 matrix that I'd expect for SVD.

Is there a simple way (i.e., other than checking the shape of `M`, the shape `s`, and then using `hstack` or `vstack`) to create $\Sigma$ and reconstruct `M`?

Comment: There are examples in the docstring: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html

Comment: Thanks. Missed that. Must be time for bed.